# How to stretch div to 100% width inside material ui TableBody

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, material-ui

I'm trying to display a CircularProgress centered inside material UI TableBody. The below is what I have tried, but it's not centered as I expected. (Please note that only relevant code has been posted)

```js
const styles = (theme) => ({
  progress: {
    width: "100%",
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "center",
    minHeight: "10vh",
    alignItems: "center"
  }
})

<TableBody>
 <div className={classes.progress}>
   <CircularProgress />
 </div> 
</TableBody>
```

It looks like this, but I want it to be centered in the `TableBody`. Currently, it only takes the width of the first column.

[image]

Comment: What are the styles on `CircularProgress` component?

Comment: No styles have been applied to it

Comment: Yes, it is 100%. I checked by applying background color to it. It takes the full width

Answer (score 0):

Here your div extends 100% to the parent which is **TableBody** you can make table body 100% or give `position: 'absolute'` to div

Comment: I tried making `TableBody` 100%, but it didn't work. When I make div absolute, it extends out of the table body. So, unfortunately, none of these solutions fixed my problem.